# JMeter: JMeter remote test fails with error as "Engine is busy, Please try later"

Tags: jmeter, distributed

I am trying to execute remote test using JMeter but it fails and shows message as "Engine is busy, Please try later".

1. JMeter versions used in all machines are similar
2. I could run remote test earlier, however, the same cannot be achieved now

Below is the log:

```html
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 10.0.11.124 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine:  10.0.11.125 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Thu Aug 27 16:30:47 IST 2015 (1440673247406) 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:47 ERROR - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.lang.IllegalStateException: Engine is busy - please try later 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 10.0.11.125 basedir='.' 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {} 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 10.0.11.125 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2015/08/27 16:30:48 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2015/08/27 16:30:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,10.0.11.125) 
2015/08/27 16:30:49 ERROR - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.lang.IllegalStateException: Engine is busy - please try later 
2015/08/27 16:30:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,10.0.11.125) 
2015/08/27 16:30:51 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started
```

Please help me with solution if I am missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen in case of connectivity issues between jmeter-client and jmeter-server.

You should restart all servers and client and try from clean state. If it persists, check jmeter.log on all servers to see what's the problem.

Comment: Another factor worth considering is the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

As extension of UBIKs answer, here are the commands I run to do that:

On every runner (slave) do the following:
1. `` kill -9 `pidof java` `` 
**This will kill all Java processes so be careful if running other applications.**

2.cd into apache-jmeter/bin directory and type `./jmeter-server &`

Then you should be able to successfully restart your test from master.